# VBA compare date from the inputbox with the date in the sheet

Tags: vba

I would like to use the date from inputbox , then compare it with the date in the excel sheet , so my code as below :

```
Sub test()
        Dim date1 As Date
        Date = InputBox("input the date ")
        If date1 = Sheet3.Range("A2").Value Then
            Debug.Print "TRUE"
        Else
                Debug.Print "FALSE"
        End If
        
End Sub
```

the result it got is always "FALSE" in the immediate box although i have set the date match with the date inputted from inputbox , can you please assist on this case ? Any assist is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *InputBox* always returns a *string*, so convert this:

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim Date1 As Date
    Dim Value As String

    Value = InputBox("Input the date")

    If IsDate(Value) Then
        Date1 = DateValue(Value)
        If DateDiff("d", Date1, Sheet3.Range("A2").Value) = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "TRUE"
        Else
            Debug.Print "FALSE"
        End If
    Else
        Debug.Print "N/A"
    End If
        
End Sub
```

Comment: If the user entered a wrong date (wrong format, for example), the procedure will not print anything, so the user will not know the result

Comment: When programming, you must mobilise a bit of creativity. Nevertheless, I've extended the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

A short solution, protected against the error of mismatching the type of input data and the data on the sheet (text or error instead of date in a cell)

```
Debug.Print IIf(InputBox("Input the date: ") = Sheet3.Range("A2").Text, "TRUE", "FALSE")
```